# What options are there to make visiting a website faster with Selenium and Tor browser?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, tor

I want to make visiting websites much faster with Selenium. Does someone know, What I can do here? I already know that I should switch off Javascript or images, for example, but what else is there?

Here is my code. You can ignore the fact that I am using the Tor Browser (that is why it is very slow):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


torexe = os.popen(r'C:\Users\Max\Desktop\Tor_Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe')
profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\Max\Desktop\Tor_Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", True)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", False)


browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path=r'C:\Users\Kinder\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')



browser.get("https://check.torproject.org/")
```

Can anyone give me a code to put in there?
Thanks

Comment: You are asking XYProblem http://xyproblem.info/ - You do not tell what is what you try to do and why you are using Tor browser. If you would state the actual problem people could help you to solve it without Tor browser.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa It's just about: I use Tor (that can't be changed) and I want to speed it up BECAUSE it's so slow. There is no real "problem", but I want to know what are the possibilities to speed it up

Comment: I have a similar problem and would like to know a solution too. I'm not using the Tor Browser, but I'm wondering what other ways are there to make the script faster?

Comment: I suggest then contributing towards Tor network and Tor project, either by running nodes or as donating money, to make it better.

Comment: do you need the proxy? That may help speed (slightly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `threading`, to leverage multiple CPU. The result will be multiple open selenium independent windows which cannot communicate with each other but you will be going through multiple parallel Tor circuits which will improve speed.

From python point of view, you have done everything possible to speed up loading pages.

These are circuits which are slowing you down. Needless to say, the speed effect will scale with more circuits and Tor browser windows opened.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try that out :-)

Comment: Hi, would you mind sharing choosing the most appropriate response and upvoting? Otherwise your bounty will just disappear :(

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. If you are using Tor browser, it is going to be considerably slower.

Answer (score -1):

Usually executing with Chrome Browser is much faster than the other browsers

Comment: the questions specifies Tor browser specific solution.

Comment: Agree and in question itself the answer is there. As I mentioned Executing with chrome Browser is much faster than the other browser. Tor browser execution is slow in comparison to Chrome.If possible change the browser to chrome.